# Yii2 acceptance tests. Rollback all changes that were made in acceptance test after each test

Tags: yii2, codeception, acceptance-testing

I need to revert all changes that were made in database by acceptance test after each acceptance test.

As described in Yii2 docs, you should set `transaction: false` for `Yii2` module in `acceptance.suite.yml`.
And you should use `cleanup: true and transaction: true` for `Db` module in `codeception.yml`.

**Actual:** changes that acceptance test did in database are **not** reverted.

**Expected:** changes that acceptance test did in database are reverted.

*codeception.yml*

```
namespace: common\tests
actor_suffix: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
modules:
    config:
        Yii2:
            configFile: 'config/test-local.php'
        Db:
            dsn: '%TEST_DB_TYPE%:host=%TEST_DB_HOST%;port=%TEST_DB_PORT%;dbname=%TEST_DB_NAME%'
            user: '%TEST_DB_USERNAME%'
            password: '%TEST_DB_PASSWORD%'
            cleanup: true
            transaction: true
params:
    - config/params-local.php
```

*acceptance.suite.yml*

```
suite_namespace: frontend\tests\acceptance
actor: AcceptanceTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - WebDriver
    - Yii2
  config:
    Yii2:
      part: init
      transaction: false
      cleanup: true
    WebDriver:
      browser: chrome
      url: 'http://mysite.dev/'
      port: 9515 # ChromeDriver port
      window_size: 1920x1080
      clear_cookies: true
      restart: true
      capabilities:
        chromeOptions:
          args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu"]
          binary: "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"

extensions:
  enabled:
  - Codeception\Extension\RunProcess:
    - chromedriver --url-base=/wd/hub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii2 module has no effect on execution of your application code in acceptance tests.

It is impossible to know what changes were made to database by your application, so your only option is to restore database from backup.

In order to have database in a known state before test you can load SQL file by using `dump` option of [DB module](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Db#Dump), but don't do that for your production database.

Comment: So transaction: true (without using dump) for Db module also wont work?

As transaction: true should wrap all queries that were made in test into transaction and rollback transaction in the end of test. 
That works for unit & func tests but not for acceptance..

Comment: It won't wrap queries made by application code, because your application is using a different connection to database.